# No detection on googlecolab or Kaggle kernel

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle, conv-neural-network, darknet

I am creating an Automatic license plate recognition for Indian plates. I trained separate models for vehicle detection, license plate detection, and character recognition. I am trying to extract frames from video and process one at a time.

I am using the [this darknet](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/tree/master/darknet) framework.

[my code on github](https://github.com/ramcho3855/alpr-for-indian-vehicles)

The problem is whenever I run it on my local machine it works fine and gives the following output:
[see this image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAKLS.png)

```
Searching for license plates...
     Processing samples/output/2_1car.png
     Processing samples/output/2_0car.png
Performing Character Recognition...
    Scanning samples/output/2_0car_lp.png
        LP: RJ47CA3205
    Scanning samples/output/2_1car_lp.png
        LP: RJ17CA1931
```

But when I run my system on googlecolab or Kaggle kernel it detects no objects.

[see this image of the output on Kaggle kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CTgG.png)

```
Loading weights from data/cr/cr.weights...Done!
Searching for vehicles...
    Scanning temp/frames/1.jpg
        0 cars found
Searching for license plates...
Performing Character Recognition...
```

I have no clue I am doing wrong. And I have been at this for what seems hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you don't have weight file  `data/cr/cr.weights` in kaggle kernel and colab

Comment: It is  Scanning `temp/frames/1.jpg` but in your local host it is `samples/output/2_0car_lp.png` Can you check `temp/frames/1.jpg`?

Comment: I do have weight files. You need to download weights file from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnXi_oPDPzDVYQS6LNnh5qrGLoac3Ntb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After downloading weights you need to run the following command to perform detection on video. `!bash video.sh -i samples/video/12.mp4 -o samples/output -c samples/output/results.csv`. The program will automatically fetch the frames and put them into the `temp/frames` directory. for instance, you can use this video file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sy_5XfEcttOc9poiByUqkNEOodCRywWC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow found the answer by myself. I modified the configuration file for all models.

```
# Testing
batch=1
subdivisions=1
# Training
#batch=256
#subdivisions=64
```

For testing change batch and subdivision to 1 and it will work.